# After placing ItemsControl item on canvas, get its Transform (Silverlight 5)

Tags: silverlight, position, mouseevent, transform, itemscontrol

I position items from a collection on a canvas using an ItemsControl. The positioning is done by a TranslateTransform: `<TranslateTransform X="{Binding x}" Y="{Binding y}"/>`. To make the items clickable, I implemented the MouseLeftButtonUp event on the items.

See the complete code below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding XYPoints}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" MouseLeftButtonUp="XYPlotPoint_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding x}" Y="{Binding y}"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                </Ellipse >
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

What I cannot figure out is this: I want to be able to click on any of my items and get the TranslateTransform coordinates, i.e. the x and y values that were used to position the element on the canvas.

My idea was to get this from the sender of the event after casting the sender back to an Ellipse, e.g. `Ellipse myEllipse = (Ellipse)sender;` but I don't see any property that contains the information.

If I use `GeneralTransform gt = myEllipse.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);` it only gives me the Transform relative to the RootVisual, not to the grid I'm drawing on.

Perhaps I am overlooking something obvious here. I'd be grateful for any hint.

Comment: You want to find the x and y values of your translate transform. Aren't those bound from your DataContext? Just get the DataContext and inspect the x and y values.

Comment: Thanks Josh, how would I do that? And after I have the `DataContext`, which is an `ObservableCollection` of, say, a thousand items with x and y position values, how would I know which item corresponds to the one I just clicked?

Comment: I found another solution to the problem, see below. If it is also possible the way you describe, Josh, I'd like to hear more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To get the transform of an `UIElement` (my item) that was clicked on relative to another `UIElement` (in my case the `Grid` it is placed on, which is also the `LayoutRoot`):

```
        private void XYPlotPoint_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //cast sender to original type
        Ellipse myEllipse = (Ellipse)sender;

        //get the transform relative to the LayoutRoot
        GeneralTransform gt = myEllipse.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);

        //transform a new point to get the coordinates
        var myUiElementPosition = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your issue is, but I guess I've got it.

You're using a very strange approach to positioning items in a `Canvas`. It's your approach that makes it so difficult to get click support. You just make all your items live over each other. You just render them in different places, while the layout and input systems think that all items are at the coordinate system origin. That's why all mouse events don't work.

The mainstream approach is via its attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, as shown in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). Try binding the properties via the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding XYPoints}">

  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" MouseLeftButtonUp="XYPlotPoint_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Canvas.X" Value="{Binding x, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Y" Value="{Binding y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```

Once you do it like this, your `MouseLeftButtonUp` event will get fired only when user clicks the very item, and you won't need to calculate the positions of the clicked items.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, but that is not the problem. Clicking on any of the items will fire the corresponding mouse events, the question is what to do inside the trigger function (e.g. inside MouseLeftButtonUp) to get the data I want. Also, there is no `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` in Silverlight, which is why I am using a `Transform` to positon the items.

Comment: @Nuitari Oops, my fault for 'ItemContainerStyle'. Damn, it exists in WPF. Why is it not there in SL???...